# Converting pictex to eps

Tags: diagrams, conversion

I have a very old pictex code which I used more than 20 years ago with plain tex. Is there a sensible way to convert it to vector graphics (eps)?

EDIT: the sample code

```
\input pictex

$$
\beginpicture
\setcoordinatesystem units <.6mm,1.1mm>
\setplotarea x from -64 to 104, y from 9 to 38
\arrow <6pt> [.2,.67] from 2 2 to 40 40
\setlinear \plot 32 32 62 2 /
\setlinear \plot 60 4 58 2 /
\arrow <6pt> [.2,.67] from 99 29 to 88 40
\setlinear \plot 66 2 96 32 /
\setlinear \plot 70 2 68 4 /
\setdashes  <2pt>
\linethickness =.3pt
\putrule from -2.2 4 to 102 4
\setsolid
\put {$\vdots$} at 32 0
\put {$\dots$} [l] at 103 24
\multiput{${\bullet}$} at 32 32  96 32
                        16 16  48 16  80 16
          8 8  24 8  40 8  56 8  72 8  88 8
          4 4  12 4  20 4  28 4  36 4  44 4
         52 4  60 4  68 4  76 4  84 4  92 4 /
\endpicture
$$

\bye
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Without seeing the underlying code, it's going to be difficult to provide specific advice.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward - basically just a planar graph with straight edges

Comment: It is probably easier to convert your top level tex input to pstricks or tikz and get scalable drawing that way, than to convert the pictex generated diagram. Would be easier to be specific if you posted an example to test...

Comment: Yes - that's what I meant. I have added the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I add `\nopagenumbers` to the code above, saved as `graph.tex`, then do

```
pdftex graph
pdfcrop graph
```

I get the following

[image]

Getting an EPS from the PDF is easy, if you really need EPS.

A rather straightforward translation into TikZ/PGF:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.6mm,y=1.1mm]
\draw[->] (2,2)--(40,40);
\draw (32,32)--(62,2);
\draw (60,4)--(58,2);
\draw[->] (99,29)--(88,40);
\draw (66,2)--(96,32);
\draw (70,2)--(68,4);
\draw[dashed] (-2.2,4)--(102,4);
\node at (32,0) {$\vdots$};
\node at (103,24) {$\dots$};
\foreach \x/\y in {
  32/32, 96/32, 16/16, 48/16, 80/16, 8/8,
  24/8, 40/8, 56/8, 72/8, 88/8, 4/4, 12/4,
  20/4, 28/4, 36/4, 44/4, 52/4, 60/4, 68/4,
  76/4, 84/4, 92/4
} { \node at (\x,\y) {$\bullet$}; }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but this is not quite what I meant, since (as far as I understand) pictex renders lines as bunches of dots, and this is what one gets after running pdftex (the lines are jagged at high zoom levels). I would rather like to get something scalable.

Comment: @RW Reimplementing PiCTeX to use modern tools such as TikZ/PGF can surely be done. But I don't think it's worth the pain.

Comment: @RW I added a translation into TikZ